# Clonk noise while braking from rear of the car

Tags: astra

While driving today, I suddenly heard this noise that seemed coming from the rear of the car. 
It seems like its coming from the left rear of the car, but be sure nor can I be sure it is coming from the tyre. When driving the car feels fine, handling is fine and hard or soft braking is all as normal. It seems to happen when driving in very low speeds while applying the brake softly, and what is strange that it is not continues and it doesn't happen all the time, while one time its louder and another time can barely be heard..... I can't feel any vibration on the wheel or brake pedal, but the passenger on the left front side of the car can feel the nock like its coming from underneath the seat.
If I accelerate and brake hard (like emergency stop), at the point when the car stops you can hear this clonk noise and feel like someone just kicked the back of your seat just so ever lightly. But even that does not happen every time.

What could it possibly be ? I'm confused, and don't want to drive the car in case it will get worse. (and the car is only one year old, no tyres changet on it yet).

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Find the bottle underneath the passenger side seat and put it somewhere it can´t move around.

Comment: Daniel. That’s funny. Been there done that. Bottles under seat can do terrible things (particularly with airbag weight sensor under front passenger seat). One idea to aid in troubleshooting odd noises. Find a quiet street or alley that has long brick wall. Roll windows down turn off A/C and radio. Do your testing there. Noises will bounce off the brick wall helping you identify location of unusual noise. Drive both directions up the alley and listen. It should be obvious which side of car is affected.

Comment: And this may be something minor but it could be something quite dangerous. You will want to look closely at affected area pronto. Loose things get worse and sometimes bad results occur.

Comment: Daniel, That was one of my first thoughts, but there is nothing riling around the car. Spoken with my dad who is a vehicle mechanic and he said it could possibly be a loose screw in moving parts within drive or suspension.  I got the car booked to be looked at a garaged in a week, will let you know the outcome. This is the most strangest issue I have come accross